# Call to a member function storeAs() on null while uploading image

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to upload image to my database, everything seems on purpose but when I upload the image I get following error:

> Call to a member function storeAs() on null

It seems normal but I still get that error.

**Controller**

```
function Create(Request $request){
        $book = Book::create([
            'name' => $request->book_name,
            'writer_name' => $request->writer_name,
            'isbn' => $request->book_isbn,
            'image' => $request->file('book_image')->storeAs('public/images', $id.'.jpg'),
        ]);
        $book->save();
        return redirect('/');
    
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<input class="form-control" type="file" name="book_image" id="book_image" placeholder="Image">
```

**Route**

```
Route::post('create','EditController@Create');
```

Comment: What does your `<form>` tag look like?

Comment: @TimLewis <form  method="POST" action="update">

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're uploading Images to Laravel, you need to include the proper `enctype`:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url('/update') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  @csrf
  <input class="form-control" type="file" name="book_image" id="book_image" placeholder="Image">
  ...
</form>
```

If you don't include `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, `$request->file('book_image')` will always be `null`.

As a sidenote, you should probably add some form of Validation for this to enforce that an image is being uploaded, and it is a valid image format:

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-required
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-image

To display the image, you *should* be able to use the following:

```
@foreach($books as $book)
  <img src="{{ asset($book->image) }}"/>
@endforeach
```

Edit: Drop the word `public` from the `saveAs()` method:

```
'image' => $request->file('book_image')->storeAs('images', uniqid().'.jpg')
```

That way, it *should* work with `asset()` helper.

Comment: Did you actually upload an image? Try the following: upload an image and do `dd($request->file('book_image'))` in your Controller, then add the output to your question (unless it's `null`; then you've got a different issue)

Comment: It doesn't return null, neither it doesn't return image. It returns something this https://imgur.com/a/hoalK8t

Comment: Perfect! That means your image is being passed correctly to the Controller. Are you sure you're getting the same error as before?

Comment: It doesn't give any error but I can't see the image on my 'public/images' folder. On front-end, in book_image section I see 'public/images/4'

Comment: Have you run the command `php artisan storage:link`?

Comment: No, I never ran it. Should I?

Comment: Yeah, you shouldn't be uploading directly to your `public_path()`, but rather to `storage/app/public`, which is symlinked to `public/images` via that command... 1 sec, let me find the documentation for that

Comment: I changed the path to 'public/images', but it's still the same

Comment: I saw the images now on storage\app\public\images directory.

Comment: Cool; so it seems to be uploading to the correct place, but you can't display images from that folder directly, which is what the symlink command does. Here's the documentation for file uploads: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem

Comment: It uploads the image to public\storage\images - I don't know why but I can't display it :( The source is src="public/storage/images/dasdas.jpg" but it displays this https://imgur.com/a/EeBKdy1 - please help me

Comment: `public/storage/images/dasdas.jpg` is not the correct URL. Try with `<image src="{{ asset('images/dasdas.jpg') }}"/>` *Please* use Laravel's functions; you're using Laravel, so use the tools available to you (I said the same thing on another one of your questions)

Comment: I'm using @foreach to show every item I have, and I've successfully displayed the image using '<td><img src="{{ asset('storage/images/'.$book->id.'.jpg') }}"></td>' But its now like this https://imgur.com/a/mxe0FEA - is there a way to avoid to find unused images?

Comment: I'm very new to Laravel, so I don't know the functions much. Sorry for that

Comment: No need to apologize; Also, wouldn't you just be able to do `<image src="{{ asset($book->image) }}"/>`? Since you're setting the path to the `books.image` column. Also, to avoid showing them, simply wrap your `<image/>` in an `@if($book->image) ... @endif`. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you, I have a last question... 'image' => $request->file('book_image')->storeAs('public/images', $request->id.'.jpg'()), My code looks like this now, but it doesnt save the extension... Am I doing it wrong or is there a another way to do it?

Comment: It should, but your code looks off; `.jpg())` looks like a typo?

Comment: Now it saves the extension but without the ID :/

Comment: Update your question with the code you're using now; it's a little unclear what code you're using from the comments (formatting them in the comments is a little difficult to read)

Comment: I find the cause of this. I'm using '$request->id' on creating, Laravel can't find the ID because the column has not created yet.  '$request->id' works on edit page because there is /edit/"ID" on page's URL.

Comment: Ah, yeah, that makes sense. And yeah, `$id` in the `Create()` method is currently undefined. You can either defer the image association until after, or use something else, like `uniqid().'.jpg'` as the filename. It won't match the ID of the book, but that's OK.

Comment: uniqid() worked, I don't know why but I can't see the image again... src="http://localhost:8000/public/images/5f35b0d44bdfc.jpg" is the source, "public\storage\images\5f35b0d44bdfc.jpg" is the path to the image but it's still undisplayed...

Comment: <img src="{{ asset($book->image) }}" > is the code in view

Comment: Hmm, might be doubling up with `asset()`. Does it work with `<img src="{{ $book->image }}"/>`? I forget what the return of `storeAs()` is, but if it's the full path, then using `asset()` around that would be the wrong URL.

Comment: Nope :( It still displays the 'undefined image' icon

Comment: Also the path in src stood the same

Comment: What's the output of `dd($book)`?

Comment: Ah, sorry, you have to expand the `attributes` property, or `dd($book->toArray())`

Comment: Yeah, you can see the word `public` in your `image` column, and `asset()` doesn't work with that. If you keep the code as you have it now, but change the save to `->storeAs('images', ...)`, then it should work. I'll update my answer again, 1 sec.

Comment: I made the change that you said, but the thing still persists...

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately, I am out of ideas and time... You're gonna have to do some self-debugging on your own for a bit; I'll revisit this tomorrow if you're still having an issue. Feel free to remove the accepted flag from my answer. Or, considering asking a new related question; this one has evolved from a single error to a whole image upload module, and is getting a little broad.

Comment: Thank you for everything, and wasting your time for my useless project. God bless you Tim

Comment: Happy to help, and your project is not useless; this is almost eerily similar to the first coding take-home test that got me my first coding career (Tourism locations database with Image upload module), so if you can nail this, you're in a pretty good spot :) Keep reading the documentation on Laravel file uploads, and see if you overlooked something. Best of luck!

Comment: Hey Tim! I just fixed the problem with adding /storage/ to asset. Now my display code is like this: asset('/storage/'.$book->image) It works perfectly, thank you for all your help!